# SSL Certificate issue msgrapgh sdk java

Tags: java, azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Using Msgrapgh SDK java in my application to Azure AD.  Deployed in weblogic server.

Below exception it is throwing:
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.
provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

how do I set the certificate to msgraph sdk java. is there way to add keys url.

Thanks
Murali

Comment: Have you looked at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62809266/azure-pkix-path-building-failed-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertpathbuil?

Comment: Thanks. it didn't resolve the issue

Comment: Are you still looking for any help on this  question

Comment: I did a temporary fix i.e disable the certificate validation.